# Issue with Projections from WGS1984 to GCS_Amersfoort

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap, arcgis-10.6, netherlands

I am using ***ArcGIS 10.6.1***. I have data from **TOP10NL** that displays the road network shapefile, and I have the busline shapefile from **openOV**. The TOP10NL data is in **GCS_Amersfoort**, the coordinate system for the Netherlands. The openOV data is in **WGS1984**. I tried projecting the data from *WGS1984 to GCS_Amersfoort* (1st time) and then from *WGS1984 to RD_New* (the projected coordinate system for the Netherlands). I left the geograhpic transformation box blank both times, as normally it autoselects. There were no drop-down options for the geographic transformation.

The data is visualizing, but the bus line shapefile from openOV does not line up with the road network shapefile from TOP10NL as it should. I don't know what else could be wrong, but this seems to me to be an issue stemming from the bus line data being in WGS1984.

In image: Road network in GCS_Amersfoort shown in green, bus line network re-projected into GCS_Amersfoort shown in purple
[image: Road network in GCS_Amersfoort shown in green, bus line network re-projected into GCS_Amersfoort shown in purple]

Answer (score 1):

I first had to project from **WGS1984** to **WGS1984 UTM 32N**, and then from there convert to **RD_NEW**. Visually, the two layers are now aligned.